# Entity Framework - Modeling multiple roles for same entity

Tags: entity-framework-6, domain-model

I have a contact class

```
[Table("Contacts")]
public class Contact
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have two classes inheriting from Contact:

```
[Table("Employees")]
public class Employee : Contact
{
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}

[Table("Suppliers")]
public class Supplier : Contact
{
    public string TIN { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Entity Framework 6.3 as my ORM.

> Can I model something where the same contact can be both Employee and
>   Supplier with the same unique Id.

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.Id = "C1";
emp.Name = "Employees";
emp.Salary = 10000;
emp.TrackingState = TrackingState.Added;

Supplier sup = new Supplier();
sup.Id = "C1";
sup.Name = "Employees";
sup.TIN = "ABC";
sup.TrackingState = TrackingState.Added;
```

When I do:

```
context.Employee.Add(emp);
context.Supplier.Add(sup);
context.Save();
```

Obviously, it will not allow me to add the record.
I get an error:

**"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Contacts'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Contacts'. The duplicate key value is (C1).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."**

> Can I make the Supplier also share the same Id as that of employee and
>   enable insert / update of employee and supplier?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are not doing any specific inheritance mapping which by default will map this as Table per Hierarchy (TPH) inheritance. With this mapping you get a single Db table that contains the aggregate of all the fields in the base type and the dependent types with a discriminator field to know which type the row should be materialized. This allows for doing a query where you ask for a type.

With TPH each row can only be a single type, so you can not have the same row be both an Employee and Supplier.

There is another type of mapping you can do called Table Per Type (TPT) which will create a table for each type, so in your case 3, one for the shared fields, and one for each dependent type. This should allow for what you are asking about. (YMMV)

However, it seems to be that Employee and Supplier would be used in much different domains so I would suggest that you create your Contact table and relate it to both your employee and supplier.

```
[Table("Contacts")]
public class Contact
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("Employees")]
public class Employee
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ContactId { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }

    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

[Table("Suppliers")]
public class Supplier
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ContactId { get; set; }
    public string TIN { get; set; }

    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can query for an employee:

```
db.Employees.Include(e => e.Contact).First();
```

Or for a Supplier:

```
db.Employees.Include(e => e.Contact).First();
```

Which might be cleaner than the inheritence query you would need:

```
db.Contacts.OfType<Employee>().First();
```

In both the Has A modeling I show above and the Is A Modeling with TPT you are getting three tables. You just have the FK in what I show rather than the same ID in 3 tables with TPT.

There is also Table Per Class you can look at, which is similar to TPT but you don't get a table for the abstract/parent class, rather you get table for each dependent type with all the fields in it. I don't think this is what you want because it would have duplicate data, however, it does mean less joins.

Comment: Thanks. This looks very good. But is there any possibility to implement this with a IsA relationship.

Comment: As I said, use a TPT or TPC mapping and you should be able to have the same Id as both types. However, I think your really fighting the framework doing this.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this with TPT mapping. I get the error mentioned in the post above.

Comment: Right, because it thinks your adding a new Entity so it will want to add a row to contacts for each dependent entity type.